tmux session not accessible on AWS EC-2 (amazon linux) but the script that was started in the tmux session continues to run
I install tmux on my EC2 instance using:
yum install tmux 

then i start a tmux session using:
tmux new -s bot

within this session, i run a python script using:
python myscript.py

this script runs perpetually, interacting with various API's, and generating and saving data to a database.
then i close the tmux session by pressing ctrl+d followed by a press of b.
Then i close the aws webpage that i was typing the above commands into.
When i reconnect to the EC2 instance (again through the web interface) and I type
tmux ls

i get the following error:
error connecting to /tmp/tmux-1000/default (No such file or directory)

when i type "tmux attach -t bot" (the session i had created was called 'bot'), it says
no sessions

however, i know for a fact that the python script that i started running within the bot session is continuing to run because I get periodic updates .
i've tried rebooting the instance, and this keeps happening. is there something i can do to fix this without terminating the instance and starting a new one? I never had this problem before in the past few months of using tmux on EC-2. tmux sessions would always persist until recently

This error indicates that something has deleted the socket file that tmux client uses to communicate with the tmux server:
error connecting to /tmp/tmux-1000/default (No such file or directory)

You can try re-creating the directories and tell to the tmux server to re-create the socket:
mkdir -p /tmp/tmux-1000
chmod 700 /tmp/tmux-1000
killall -SIGUSR1 tmux
ls -l /tmp/tmux-1000
tmux attach

This should do the trick.
